# h.264 and 1440p/2160p in Cobalt

Tags: cobalt

Playback of 1440p/2160p content with h.264 encoding from the Cobalt test suites (YT2018 spec) fail for us on Broadcom chipset. Are these test cases even supposed to work?

The Cobalt linux-x64x11 cannot play h.264 1440p and 2160p content either, and as far as I know, all YouTube content above HD is encoded with VP9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jan Boquist, that is expected and not relevant to the browser(or Cobalt) you use. If you have further questions about this, please reach out to your YouTube technical account manager.